# How to install headers from source instead of dev package

Tags: c, curl, debian, header-files, package-managers

I need to install headers from curl source so I can use a function added recently.

Source is downloaded and compiled

What to do with files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Cheap way: Copy the headers to where you need them.</strike>

Professional way: From the patched sources build the (patched) dev-package using your OS/distro's package manager tools and install it.

Misread the question.

To include the curl headers and to link against `liccurl` install the related dev-package using your distro's package manager.

For Debian based systems this were:

- aptitude
- aptget
- dpkg
- ...

Please note that there might be several dev-package using different authentication/encryption libraries.

- libcurl4-gnutls-dev
- libcurl4-openssl-dev
- ...

You need to decide which one you prefer.

Comment: please link to instructions to build dev package

Comment: The link depends on the OS (version/distribution) you use.

Comment: debian 8, tis old

Comment: You might like to drill you way down from here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1345/what-is-the-simplest-debian-packaging-guide

Comment: The "cheap way" definitely is the faster way. If you want to create your own packages strongly depends on your needs, which we do not know.

Comment: @alk they're not asking for packaging instructions. They only want to extract what's in the dev package and install it (the "professional way"). Or use the header files form the curl sources.